# Can a patricia trie contain duplicate keys

Tags: perl, duplicates, key, trie

More specifically can a patricia trie:

http://search.cpan.org/~plonka/Net-Patricia-1.014/Patricia.pm

Contain duplicate IP addresses (duplicate key IP with different values)
and if so how does it handles returning the values from that key?

ie:

```
123.456.789.0-> {
  'value' => 'hai'
}

123.456.789.0->{
  'value' => 'hey there'
}



patricia-trie->match_string(123.456.789.0)
```

returns  ???

Edit:
Yes, I know I can implement my own that supports this behavior. I am asking how this specific trie implementation handles it.  The documentation is extremely limited and manual testing appears to show overwrites, but I was hoping someone has a definitive answer.

Comment: Have you tried it? This sounds like a question you could answer yourself with a few more minutes of investigation

Answer (score 0):

A trie (or Patricia tree) is generally a map between keys and values. To make a map into a multimap, use a linked list or array as the value.